# List of KVO properties?

Tags: ios, avplayer, key-value-observing

Where can I find a list of observable properties for the AVPlayer? 
I can't seem to find it anywhere in Apple docs.

Comment: Can we find KVO props for NSString or NSArray ?

Comment: You should accept an answer if one has helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use KVO only if you are told by the docs that this is safe / proper behavior. Basically, to obtain your list, you just have to search on the word "observable" or "observe" or "observing".

So, for AVPlayer, consulting [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html), under the `status` property documentation, we read:

> This property is key value observable **using key-value observing**

Similarly, under the `outputObscuredDueToInsufficientExternalProtection` property documentation, we read:

> You can observe changes to the value of this property **using key-value observing**

Thus, the answer is: The `status` property of AVPlayer, and its `outputObscuredDueToInsufficientExternalProtection` property, and no others, are key-value observable.

Note, however, that there are other ways of being notified of what's up with an AVPlayer, e.g. by calling `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` or `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:`.

Comment: As I understand it, the `outputObscuredDueToInsufficientExternalProtection` property is also key-value observable on `AVPlayer` according to the header.

Comment: Okay, adding that one.

Answer (score 1):

The [AVPlayer Programing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html) shows the KVO `status` key, as well as the observable notifications for `AVPlayerItem`: `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`, etc.

A full list of `AVPlayerItem` observable notifications can be found in the [AVPlayerItem docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification) under Notifications.

```
AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification
AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification
AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntryNotification
AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntryNotification
```

Additionally, the comments on properties in `AVPlayer.h` specifically state which properties are key-value observable: `status` and `outputObscuredDueToInsufficientExternalProtection`:

```
/*!
 @property status
 @abstract
    The ability of the receiver to be used for playback.

 @discussion
    The value of this property is an AVPlayerStatus that indicates whether the receiver can be used for playback. When
    the value of this property is AVPlayerStatusFailed, the receiver can no longer be used for playback and a new
    instance needs to be created in its place. When this happens, clients can check the value of the error property to
    determine the nature of the failure. This property is key value observable.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerStatus status;

// ...

@interface AVPlayer (AVPlayerProtectedContent)

/*!
    @property outputObscuredDueToInsufficientExternalProtection
    @abstract
        Whether or not decoded output is being obscured due to insufficient external protection.

    @discussion
        The value of this property indicates whether the player is purposefully obscuring the visual output
        of the current item because the requirement for an external protection mechanism is not met by the
        current device configuration. It is highly recommended that clients whose content requires external
        protection observe this property and set the playback rate to zero and display an appropriate user
        interface when the value changes to YES. This property is key value observable.

        Note that the value of this property is dependent on the external protection requirements of the
        current item. These requirements are inherent to the content itself and cannot be externally specified.
        If the current item does not require external protection, the value of this property will be NO.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL outputObscuredDueToInsufficientExternalProtection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

@end
```